# 'Unsupported SSL protocol version' Curl OpenSSL version confusion (paypal api php sdk)

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

I'm trying to work with the PayPal API php SDK (connecting to sandbox), but I'm running into the following exception:

```
Uncaught exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Unsupported SSL protocol version'
```

The code I'm using is the following:

```
$sdkConfig = array(
    "mode" => "sandbox"
);

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        xxxxxx,     // ClientID
        xxxxxx      // ClientSecret
    )
);

$apiContext->setConfig($sdkConfig); 

$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setCurrency("USD");
$amount->setTotal("12");

$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setDescription("creating a payment");
$transaction->setAmount($amount);

$redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("xxx");
$redirectUrls->setCancelUrl("xxx");

$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale");
$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

$payment->create($apiContext);
```

I've done a few hours of research on the issue and it seems to be an issue with CURL using TLSv1.2. I've used the following code to work out a few things, with results in comments beside:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($data);
echo $json->tls_version; // TLS 1.2

$curl_info = curl_version();
echo $curl_info['ssl_version']; // OpenSSL/1.0.0

echo OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT; // OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

- Linux CentOS 6.32 (Dedicated)
- Apache 2.4.18
- PHP 5.6.18
- CURL 7.38.0
- PayPal API PHP SDK v1.6.4 (latest as of now)

I'm not sure if it's my misunderstanding or if something is going wrong, but it seems that CURL is using OpenSSL 1.0.0, when the installed version is 1.0.1e-fips.

PayPal are making changes to their service which require OpenSSL of at least 1.0.1c (which according to PHP I have), but the exception above leads me to think that maybe CURL is using its own version, which is tripping me up.

[This issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/474) mentions someone having the same problem which resulted in v.1.6.4, but that didn't solve my issue. Another issue [here](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php/issues/64) talks more about it.

I've spent the last few hours vainly trying to upgrade CURL to version 7.46 (solved the problem in the second linked issue) via WHM, but it doesn't seem to want to go past 7.36.

Why does CURL state that its version of OpenSSL is 1.0.0, while PHP's version is 1.0.1e-fips? Can I force the OpenSSL version for CURL (PHP manual doesn't show an option for this)?

Any advice welcome.

**EDIT:**
- The SSL certificate on my app is a valid SHA-256 as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34911228/2311507)

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);

Comment: Thanks, but PayPal API explicitly requires TLSv1.2, cannot use SSLv3.

Comment: Try to downgrade CURL to 7.33 more stable and may fix the problem